# python scipy.integrate inverse ppf

Tags: python, probability-density, scipy.stats

Hello I would like what is the x value that would give me an specific numeric integral.

So far I am using scipy.integrate and works ok, but given a integral value is there a way to know what is the x that gave that result?

let say I have a function f(x) = |2-x| 1<=x<=3

I would like to know what is  the x value that give me 0.25 (the first quartile).

What in scipy.stats for normal distribution is norm.ppf(), in this particular case I am using it for PDF (probability density function) but it can be any integral.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Besides integral value what else is known? We need something to know about function itself to revert integral value. Is function given somehow? Symbolically or numerically?

Comment: Hello @Arty, as I mention in the question I have the function, and lets say the initial value for example for the function given, lets say from 1 to ? and I have the result 0.25

Comment: And how your function is given? I mean is it given as a regular python function (`def` or `lambda`). If so you can use binary search to revert integral.

Comment: I am a begginer to python,  I have the function f(x) defined between 1 and 3, I can define it as convinient in order to find the x value that makes the integral between 1 and x to give the result 0.25... does it make sense?

Comment: I posted answer with binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to find answer in [logarithmic time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Logarithmic_time) (very fast). You can also run [code below online here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow63975396#main.py).

```
import math, scipy.integrate, scipy.optimize

def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)

a, b = 0, 10
integral_value = 0.5

res_x = scipy.optimize.bisect(
    lambda x: scipy.integrate.quad(f, a, x)[0] - integral_value,
    a, b
)
print(
    'found point x', res_x, ', integral value at this point',
    scipy.integrate.quad(f, a, res_x)[0]
)
```